# How do I tell how much iCloud space my app uses?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, icloud

Is there a way to see what my app is backing up to iCloud, and how much memory it consumes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Settings > iCloud > Storage & Backup > Manage Storage` will show you the aggregate total of what is being backed up.

iOS backs up any files located in your application’s sandbox, except those located in `<Application_Home>/Library/Caches`.

[Technical Q&A QA1719](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1719/_index.html) has more on how to **not** back up data in iOS 5.0.1 and later.

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to see, you can go into Settings->iCloud->Storage & Backup->Manage Storage.

On your Mac, you can browse to "`~/Library/Mobile Documents`" and see what is being stored in the cloud, including transaction logs (iCloud and Core Data) or documents (e.g. Pages, Keynote). To be clear, it shows the contents of stuff on your iPhone/iPad which is shared using iCloud, not just Mac apps that use iCloud. You may need to enable iCloud on your Mac to see this folder.