# How do I check how much space my iPhone App is taking in the iTunes backup?

Tags: ios, ios5

How do I check how much space my iPhone App is taking in the iTunes backup?

-

If you are curious why I ask, read on...

I wrote an app, and it was rejected because I didn't exclude some big files from the iTunes backup with the NSURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey property.

Now I fixed it and maybe it works :) How can I check if it works?
If it works, the backup for that app has less than 20MB. If it didn't work, my local iTunes backup for that app is >300MB. How can I check how much space my app is taking in the iTunes backup? If I look into `~/Library/Application Support/MobileSync/Backup/` I just see two folders with random names. Each folder contains a bunch of files with random names. (And with random, I mean really random, like `4287436df27ac72...`) Btw, I'm using iTunes 11.0 (163) on Mac OS X 10.6.8, iPhone 4S with iOS 5.0.1 (which I know doesn't support NSURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey, but another mechanism with the same effect.)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I tell how much iCloud space my app uses?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10389852/how-do-i-tell-how-much-icloud-space-my-app-uses)

Comment: well, it would be if syncing to iCloud is the only way of syncing ;) but it's also possible to sync to the Mac or Windows computer.

Answer (score 1):

Open `Settings>iCloud>Storage & Backup>Manage Storage>Your device` and your app should be listed.

Comment: Do you mean the Settings on iTunes, the Settings Application in Mac OS X or the Settings App on the Device itself? Out of all three possibilities, I only find the iCloud in the Settings of the Device itself, but it is disabled, because I don't sync to the iCloud. So, nothing happens if I click on it. Do I really have to sync to the iCloud in order to see the size of the backup? Is it not possible to see the size of the backup in iTunes itself? Because I synchronize to my Mac, not to the iCloud.

Answer (score 0):

**in ITunes on a Mac:** So far I have not found a way that tells you exactly the size of an app in the backup. But it's possible to get the total size of the backup in kilobytes with `du -k ~/Library/Application\ Support/MobileSync |tail -n1` (there is a space after the `\`). So you can uninstall the app, synchronize with itunes, check the backup size, install the app, download, kill the app, synchronize again, check the backup size again. Then you can compare the sizes. If someone finds an easier way of doing this, I may accept that answer...

**with the iCloud:** On the Device, open the settings application and go to `iCloud > Storage & Backup > Manage Storage` (as hwaxxer already pointed out). In some cases this number is not useful though, because the iPhone doesn't sync every second and synchronizing takes time. So, if the App just stores 20MB in its `Documents` folder we cannot expect the number to be available in the settings just 2 seconds later. Maybe we can check an hour later if we have WLAN, maybe 10min later. If after 2min we see that the backup takes 20MB we know that it has been synced, but if we see 33kb in the settings after two minutes we don't know if the data just will not go to the backup or if the synchronization just isn't completed yet. (If I'm wrong correct me, I will accept an answer that is more helpful than this one.)